# Password expiration warnings with AIX Kerberos to Active Directory authentication

Tags: active-directory, kerberos, aix

Our environment is AIX 7.1, having a mix of local accounts and accounts in Active Directory authenticated via Kerberos.

We have observed that for local accounts, successful authentication within the password warning period also issues the expected warning message, such as:

[compat]: 3004-328 Your password will expire: Fri Apr 15 12:59:33 CDT 2022

However the Active Directory accounts do not receive such warning messages.  Is it possible to configure AIX/Kerberos to issue these messages?  If so, will it use AIX's "Days to warn user before password expires", or Active Directory's?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

•   No, you can’t configure AIX/Kerberos to issue this message to domain accounts as their password policy is managed by Active Directory Group policy and is a part of the Active Directory services. Thus, it is applicable to domain users only. And as these AD domain user accounts are not a part of AIX local user accounts, AIX server doesn’t have any authority over them due to which password expiration message regarding AIX local user accounts is not issued as same and equivalent to AD domain user accounts. Also, if you want to configure the password expiration prompt message for AD domain user accounts, you can surely do it as below: -

‘ Go to Group Policy Management -> Default Domain Policy -> Edit -> Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Security Options -> Interactive logon: Prompt user to change password before expiration -> Set the number of days ’

[image: Group Policy edit]

Comment: Thanks for the information.  Yes our AD domain users are configured in AD to receive password expiration warning messages.  They do receive those if logging in, say, using a Windows desktop.  But for our AD users logging in to AIX via terminal sessions, they are authenticated if they provide valid credentials but do not receive such warnings.   

This is somewhat baffling, as the IBM doc (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.1?topic=ugp-user-group-attributes-supported-by-authentication-load-modules) appears to indicate that "expires" is an attribute supported via the Kerberos interface.

Comment: @dablumen - When you have time.... If you found this answer helpful you should upvote it.  If you comfortable this is the answer to your question you should mark it correct.

Comment: @dablumen, please refer to these links as they state configuration related to AIX password expiry warning related to kerberos and its further extension: - https://developer.ibm.com/articles/au-aix-active_directory_integration/ ; https://developer.ibm.com/articles/au-password_expiry/